# Wagtail-ModelTranslation Template Fragment Caching

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wagtail, django-modeltranslation

I've implemented a multilingual site using wagtail and wagtail-modeltranslation but I'm having a problem with template fragment caching. The cache works but is not respecting the separate languages. Whichever language is accessed first after a save, is the one that will be served for all languages. I've tried two ways of setting the cache key to no avail. First from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching), second trying to explicitly include the language code in the template

First:

```
{% cache 604800 about_copy LANGUAGE_CODE %}
... HTML ...
{% endcache %}
```

Second: Using a simple template tag

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_lang(context, *args, **kwargs):
    return get_language()
```

```
{% cache 604800 about_copy get_lang %}
... HTML ...
{% endcache %}
```

My save method is as follows:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create a template fragment key.
        Then delete the key."""

        key = make_template_fragment_key("about_copy")
        cache.delete(key)

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This does clear the correct fragment regardless of not including any language related arguments

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach should work provided `LANGUAGE_CODE` is actually defined in the context. This doesn't happen automatically, so you probably just need to [set it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language) first:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

{% cache 604800 about_copy LANGUAGE_CODE %}
... HTML ...
{% endcache %}
```

A side note here is that you need to be careful with template fragment caching in Wagtail, because [previewed, non-published content will get cached](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5074).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the information about previews being cached, I saw your solution there and will most likely implement the same. This is my first wagtail/django project and you just save me loads of time. It turns out I didn't have **django.template.context_processors.i18n** loading in my context processors so `{% get_current_langage as LANGUAGE_CODE %}` was not working as expected. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!